# Access data disk on same machine from linux for writing

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Can't access  data disk on the same machine from linux for writing.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/armin/1T_20131122: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/armin/1T_20131122"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the data disk is a windows 8 disk? If so then afaik you can not access this partition via Linux.

I think this is due to the fact that windows 8 does not "correctly" shut down to help improve its start up times.

I would advise creating a separate NTFS partition, either resize the disk or use a new one that contains no operating systems to store your data on.